# Generate unique link for each website visitor

Tags: html, http, email, hyperlink, tracking

I send 3 different links to people on a daily basis. I know the name of the person I am sending the link to. How do I attach that persons information to the link to know they clicked on the link?

I sent close to 50 emails to different people. I just want to be notified that someone I sent the link to click on it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a database for this. The link could contain a random hash that can be looked up in the "emails" table. This table could keep records for timestamps, specifically when the emial was sent out, and when the user clicked the link.

### @QUESTION:

Most hosting providers give you the option to hook up a database. If you have trouble finding this, use google or their support. As far as how to "use" a database, you will need to learn this in you own time. But like anything else the basics are widely available through google, which in your case, is all you need to finish your project.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this a little more? I have access to host for the pages im sending links to and can create a database for this.

Comment: im assuming you have shared hosting?

Comment: Yes I also have a VPS too. The website gets very little traffic daily so I just use the shared for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an encrypted or obfuscated field to your URLs identifying the email address.

Common methods:

- `base64` encoded email address XOR-ed with known key
- `md5` hash of email address truncated to first N characters

And so on.
The first method allows you to *reverse* the process (i.e. getting back the email address from the visit log), the second is one-way only.

For example, using the second method with email `dude@gmail.com` (truncated to 12 characters):

```
http://domain.com/click.php?v=ec3ab9422d7a
```

Or, as already said, you can simply use a database and store a key-value pair `(email, hash)` with, for each email, a random string generated on-the-fly by your massmailer.