# URL links in email - resolve correct url?

Tags: email, url, hyperlink, tracking

Before i start thinking about this programatically, does anyone know if it is possible to actually extract the correct url from an email link that is basically a tracking module?

Our work email system auto blocks tracking based urls from email, so i am thinking of writing something to extract the correct url so people can copy and paste the tracking link into a program and it will provide the correct url.

Is this even possible with the way that email tracking works?

Here is an example of a url in an email that i recently received:

> http://t.dripemail2.com/c/eyJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjoiNTE0MTQ4NSIsImRlbGl2ZXJ5X2lkIjoiOTI0NzI2MTU0IiwidXJsIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuYXhzaWVkLmNvbS9nY3NlLWNvbXB1dGVyLXNjaWVuY2Uvb2NyLW5lYS1ndWlkZS8_X19zPXphb2txcDVpaWN4NGkxZndtYmNnIn0

Our system blocks these. It eventually resolves to:

> https://www.axsied.com/gcse-computer-science/ocr-nea-guide/?__s=zaokqp5iicx4i1fwmbcg

(got our network admin to check it for me)

I want a system that gets the right url from the ugly mess that is blocked so we can actually view links from emails.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The data in tracking URLs are *typically* a unique ID pointing to some entry in a database, or are encrypted with a private key, so there's no way to obtain any meaningful information from them. (see answers to this related question: [Generate unique link for each website visitor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9447031))

More naive approaches will simply encode the data, in which case you may be able to extract useful information from them. Funnily enough, your example URL is a base 64 encoded JSON object containing the link itself:

```json
{
  "account_id": "5141485",
  "delivery_id": "924726154",
  "url": "https://www.axsied.com/gcse-computer-science/ocr-nea-guide/?__s=zaokqp5iicx4i1fwmbcg"
}
```

In this case you could actually resolve the URL on your own, but this type of approach is uncommon for that very reason.